# When I run my vxml application I get this syntax error

Tags: ecmascript-5, vxml

I get this error when I run my vxml app;

> "ECMAScript runtime error: Compilation produced 1 syntax
>   errors.\n\nWhile evaluating:\n\"var acc_no = [37492414, 94190610,
>   23228367, 39574988, 64742440];\n\t\t\t\t\tfunction checkAccount(arr,
>   val) {\n\t\t\t\t\treturn arr.some(arrVal => val ===
>   arrVal);\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t} \"";

Here's my vxml script where the error arises:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<vxml xmlns:voxeo="http://community.voxeo.com/xmlns/vxml"
      version="2.1" xml:lang="en-US"
       xml:base="http://webhosting.voxeo.net/201985/www/">


    <property name="inputmodes" value="dtmf"/> 
    <property name="termchar" value="#"/>
    <property name="interdigittimeout" value="2s"/>
    <property name="bargein" value="false"/>
    <var name = "accountNumber"/>
    <var name = "pinNumber"/> 


    <form id="userAuth" scope="document">
        <var name="iMaxTries" expr="3"/>
        <var name="iTriesAcc" expr="0"/>
        <var name="iTriesPin" expr="0"/>
        <var name="fatal" expr="'We are having technical difficulties validating your credentials. Try back later.'"/>

    <catch event="event.pinNumber.invalid">
    <!-- increment the attempt counter; if the count is exceeded, disconnect -->
        <assign name="iTriesPin" expr="iTriesPin+1"/>
        <if cond="iMaxTries == iTries">
            <value expr="fatal"/>
            <disconnect/>
        <else/>
    <!-- clear is unnecessary on a nomatch, but we use the same code to handle a bad filled -->
            <clear namelist="pinNumber"/>
            <reprompt/>
        </if>
    </catch>
    <catch event="event.accountNumber.invalid">
    <!-- increment the attempt counter; if the count is exceeded, disconnect -->
        <assign name="iTriesAcc" expr="iTriesAcc+1"/>
        <if cond="iMaxTries == iTries">
            <value expr="fatal"/>
            <disconnect/>
        <else/>
    <!-- clear is unnecessary on a nomatch, but we use the same code to handle a bad filled -->
            <clear namelist="accountNumber"/>
            <reprompt/>
        </if>
    </catch>
    <!-- exec this on the first and second noinput/nomatch -->
    <!-- each event has its own counter -->
    <catch event="noinput">
        I'm sorry. I didn't get you.
        <reprompt />
    </catch>

    <!-- exec this on the third nomatch -->
    <catch event="nomatch">
        <throw event="event.password.invalid"/>
    </catch>

    <!-- silently disconnect on the third noinput -->
    <catch event="noinput" count="3">
        <disconnect/>
    </catch>


    <field name="accountNumber" type="digits?length=8">
        <prompt> Please enter your account number followed by the pound key. </prompt>
            <grammar mode="dtmf" version="1.0" root="pin"
                tag-format="semantics/1.0">
                <rule id="digit" scope="public" >
                    <one-of>
                        <item> 0 </item>
                        <item> 1 </item>
                        <item> 2 </item>
                        <item> 3 </item>
                        <item> 4 </item>
                        <item> 5 </item>
                        <item> 6 </item>
                        <item> 7 </item>
                        <item> 8 </item>
                        <item> 9 </item>
                   </one-of>
               </rule>

               <rule id="pin" scope="public">
                    <tag>out=""</tag>
                        <item repeat="8">
                            <ruleref uri="#digit"/>
                            <tag>out += rules.latest( );</tag>
                       </item>
               </rule>
           </grammar>


        <filled> 
               <script> <![CDATA[
                    var acc_no = [37492414, 94190610, 23228367, 39574988, 64742440];
                    function checkAccount(arr, val) {
                    return arr.some(arrVal => val === arrVal);
                                            }
                ]]> </script>

                <block>
                    <var name="chk_acc" expr="checkAccount(acc_no, accountNumber);"/>

                    <if cond="chk_acc =='true'">
                        <goto next="#pinNumber"/>
                    <else/>
                        <prompt>Sorry, Account number not recognised. </prompt>
                        <throw event="event.accountNumber.invalid"/>
                    </if>
                </block>

         </filled>
    </field>

    <field name="pinNumber" type="digits?length=4">
        <prompt> please enter your four digit pin followed by the pound key. </prompt>
        <grammar mode="dtmf" version="1.0" root="pin"
         tag-format="semantics/1.0">
         <rule id="digit" scope="public" >
            <one-of>
               <item> 0 </item>
               <item> 1 </item>
               <item> 2 </item>
               <item> 3 </item>
               <item> 4 </item>
               <item> 5 </item>
               <item> 6 </item>
               <item> 7 </item>
               <item> 8 </item>
               <item> 9 </item>
            </one-of>
         </rule>

         <rule id="pin" scope="public">
            <tag>out=""</tag>
            <item repeat="4">
               <ruleref uri="#digit"/>
               <tag>out += rules.latest( );</tag>
            </item>
         </rule>
       </grammar>

          <filled>

            <script> <![CDATA[
                    var pin_no = [2414, 0610,8367, 4988, 2440];
                    function checkPin(arr, val) {
                    return arr.some(arrVal => val === arrVal);
                                            }
                ]]> </script>

                <block>
                    <var name="chk_pin" expr="checkPin(pin_no, pinNumber);"/>

                    <if cond="chk_pin =='false'">
                        <prompt>Sorry, you have entered is an invalid pin. Please try again </prompt>
                        <throw event="event.pinNumber.invalid"/>    

                    </if>
                </block>

          </filled>
    </field>

    <filled mode="all" namelist="accountNumber pinNumber">


    <script> <![CDATA[
        var accDetails = [
        {acc_name: 'Lawrence Burkins', account: 37492414, pin: 2414, acc_type: 'checking', acc_bal: 2372351.74 , acc_br:'Montreal'},
        {acc_name: 'Ola Macaulay', account: 94190610, pin: 0610, acc_type: 'checking', acc_bal: 908242.49 , acc_br:'Tisdale'},
        {acc_name: 'Judy Cefalu', account: 23228367, pin: 8367, acc_type: 'checking', acc_bal: 15700526.57 , acc_br:'Toronto'},
        {acc_name: 'Mellisa Garcia', account: 39574988, pin: 4988, acc_type: 'checking', acc_bal: 568201.26 , acc_br:'Prince Albert'},
        {acc_name: '', account: 64742440, pin: 2440, acc_type: 'checking', acc_bal: 1952000.00 , acc_br:'Fort McMurray'},
                        ];

        function accDetails(details) { 
                return details.account === accountNumber ;
                            }
                var newDetail = accDetails.find(accDetails);
                var myDetail = [newDetail];
                var myBal = myDetail.slice(0, 4);

    ]]> </script>

        <var name = "accountBalance" expr = "myBal.toString()"/>

        <prompt>
        Your Checking account balance is <prosody rate="slow"><say-as type="currency"> $ + <value class="currency" expr="accountBalance"/> </say-as></prosody>
        </prompt>
        <goto next="after_bal.vxml"/>   
    </filled>
    </form>

 </vxml>
```

I am still new to vxml and ecmascript.

Comment: It depends on the VXML browser.  For example the GVP MCP uses an older version of SpiderMonkey so new Javascript features don't work on it.  What version of Javascript does your VXML browser support?

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript in question seems to be syntactically correct:

```
var acc_no = [37492414, 94190610, 23228367, 39574988, 64742440];
                    function checkAccount(arr, val) {
                    return arr.some(arrVal => val === arrVal);
                                        }
```

I would suggest breaking this piecemeal and reduce the complexity of the VXML code to debug it. Use a very basic VXML file with one simple field, put the above ECMAScript in the filled section and then see if you get the same error. If you do, move the script further up in the code (i.e not in the filled section) and again check if you get the same error.

The error statement is a bit confusing because of the linefeeds etc. Does the error message look like that when you see it the first time?